# different click actions for different screen size

Tags: jquery, width

I am trying to write 2 functions for a single click action, based on the screen width:

```
$(".view_offer_wrapper").click(function(){
    var current = $(".compare_wrapper div:last-child").index(this);
    $(".product_desc_expand").hide();
});

if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  // Different action for same click function
}
```

First click works fine, no issues with it.

But if the window size < 480, first click is initiated rather than the click function inside the if condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution is to check the condition within the click handler

```
$(".view_offer_wrapper").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        //action 1
    } else {
        //action2
        var current = $(".compare_wrapper div:last-child").index(this);
        $(".product_desc_expand").hide();
    }
});
```

Second solution is to register different click handlers based on the condition

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    $(".view_offer_wrapper").click(function () {
        //action 1
    });
} else {
    $(".view_offer_wrapper").click(function () {
        //action2
        var current = $(".compare_wrapper div:last-child").index(this);
        $(".product_desc_expand").hide();
    });
}
```

*Note: If you want to support resizing of window then you have to choose the first solution*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".view_offer_wrapper").click(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    alert('width less than 480');
   }
 else
 {
     alert('width grater than 480');
 }
});
```

You can use **if else** inside click function.